Error: "Failed to load native binding" in Strapi project using @swc/core
I'm encountering an issue while working on a Strapi project located at D:\Strapi\isha-blogs. After running the project, I receive the following error related to the @swc/core package:
Error: Failed to load native binding
            at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Strapi\isha-blogs\node_modules\@swc\core\binding.js:333:11)
            ...
        Error: Cannot find module './swc.win32-x64-msvc.node'
            Require stack:
            - D:\Strapi\isha-blogs\node_modules\@swc\core\binding.js
            - D:\Strapi\isha-blogs\node_modules\@swc\core\index.js
            - D:\Strapi\isha-blogs\node_modules\@vitejs\plugin-react-swc\index.cjs
        ...

Steps I've Tried:
1. Reinstalled Dependencies:

Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalled
dependencies using npm install.

2. Checked Node.js Version:

Verified that my Node.js version is compatible with @swc/core.

3. Manually Installed Missing Module:

Ran npm install @swc/core to ensure the correct module is installed.

4. Rebuilt Node Modules:

Tried npm rebuild to rebuild the modules.

5. Cleared npm Cache:

Cleared the npm cache using npm cache clean --force.

6. Updated @vitejs/plugin-react-swc:

Ran npm update @vitejs/plugin-react-swc to ensure the plugin is
up to date.

Environment:

OS: Windows 10
Node.js Version: v18.20.4
npm Version: 10.7.0
Strapi Version: 4.25.9
@swc/core Version:1.7.22
@vitejs/plugin-react-swc Version: 3.5.0

Additional Context:
I suspect that the issue might be related to a mismatch in the native bindings required for @swc/core, but I’m not sure how to resolve it. Is there anything I’m missing or any other steps I should try to fix this issue?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

During my installation attempt, I encountered the following issue: 'Error: Cannot find module '@swc/core-darwin-universal'' and 'throw new Error('Failed to load native binding', { cause: loadErrors })'.
After running the command 'sudo npm update', the problem was resolved.

Running npm update worked for me as well.
